# Cochran's rules for contingency table

Tags: self-study, chi-squared-test, contingency-tables

I am proposing this question for a chi-squared test of association between party and voting. The following table is based on how (R)-Republican and (D)-Democrats voted on a specific bill

```
     yes no
   R  99 11
   D   1 48
```

Since the (D, yes) cell is 1, could I be violating Cochran's rules for a chi-squared test?

Comment: What is the *expected* count for D-yes?

Comment: 30.817 found from (100*49/159)

Comment: Isn't the rule that the $\chi^{2}$ contingency table test should not be used when *expected* counts in any cell are less than 5?

Comment: @Alexis I should have specified that the table listed here is the observed counts. None of the expected count cells are less than 5

Comment: Cochran's main point under this heading was that a rule such as all expected counts being at least 5 was over-cautious.

Comment: @NickCox is spot on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:** contingency table $\chi^{2}$ tests with *expected* counts less than 5 were deemed inappropriate by Cochran, but your example is of *observed* counts.